Azure Function Deployment Failure In VScode when Using Remote Build
I’m facing an issue while deploying my Azure Function App through VS Code using the Azure CLI. The deployment process gives an error related to a remote build, even though the Function App was created very recently.
Problem Description:
I attempted to deploy my Azure Function App using the following command in VS Code:

func azure functionapp publish  --build remote

However, I received the following error message:
Remote build is a new feature added to function apps.
Your function app  does not support remote build as it was created before August 1st, 2019.
Please use '--build local' or '--build-native-deps'.
This error doesn't make sense because I created this Function App today (August 2024), so it should definitely support remote builds.
Steps I've Taken:
Checked Creation Date: I verified that the Function App was indeed created recently, well after the August 1st, 2019 cut-off mentioned in the error message.
Tried Alternative Build Methods:
I used the --build local flag, but this resulted in the same error.
I avoided using the --build-native-deps flag because my Function App is not Docker-based, and I don't believe this is the appropriate approach for my scenario.
Additional Context:
Function App Environment: The Function App is running on a Linux Consumption Plan.
Language: The Function is written in Python.
Deployment Method: I am deploying via VS Code with the Azure Functions extension, using Azure CLI for the publish command.
Expected Behavior:
Given that my Function App was created after August 2019, I expect the remote build feature to work without issues. The error message seems inaccurate, and I am unsure how to resolve this deployment problem without resorting to the --build-native-deps option, which I believe is not suitable for my use case.
Question:
Why am I encountering this incorrect error message regarding the creation date of my Function App?
What is the proper way to resolve this issue and successfully deploy my Function App using remote build?
I’d appreciate any insights or solutions from the community.

As mentioned in the MSDOC:

You may have issues with remote build when your app was created before the feature was made available (August 1, 2019). For older apps, either create a new function app or run  az functionapp update --resource-group <RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME> --name <APP_NAME>  to update your function app. This command might take two tries to succeed.

To resolve this error, validate the storage connection string used in the function app and local.settings.json.

Create a new storage account using the command:

az storage account create \
    --name <storage_name> \
    --resource-group <rg_name> \
    --location <location> \
    --sku Standard_LRS

local.settings.json:
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
    "Values": {
        "AzureWebJobsStorage": "<Storage_connection_string>",
        "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet-isolated"
    }
}


Able to deploy the function to Azure using the command func azure functionapp <functionappname> --build remote:

C:\Users\uname\Source\Repos\FunctionApp14>func azure functionapp publish kpfunc19 --build remote

Getting site publishing info...
[2024-08-19T07:59:19.798Z] Starting the function app deployment...
Updating Application Settings for Remote build...
Creating archive for current directory...
Performing remote build for functions project.
Uploading 13.23 KB [##############################################################################]
Upload completed successfully.
[2024-08-19T08:03:21.764Z] Syncing triggers...
Functions in kpfunc19:
    Function1 - [httpTrigger]
        Invoke url: https://kpfunc19.azurewebsites.net/api/function1

